# How to align content inside two divs of different width at 50% height?

Tags: css, html, alignment

There are two div-containers: leftcontainer covers the left half of my screen, rightcontainer the right half. Inside both containers is a textbox with variable height

```
.leftcontainer{
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    width:60%;
    height:100%;
}
.rightcontainer{
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    width:40%;
    height:100%;
}
.textbox{
    margin-top: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    background:#333333;
}
```

```
<div class="leftcontainer">
    <div class="textbox">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore
    </div>
</div>
<div class="rightcontainer">
    <div class="textbox">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the textboxes to be horizontally aligned: both should start at 50% height. But they are only aligned, if I set the width of leftcontainer and rightcontainer both to 50%.
If I do

```
.leftcontainer{width:60%;}
.rightcontainer{width:40%;}
```

the right text box moves up. Could someone tell me, how to fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Would you object to a different approach? http://jsfiddle.net/CnJXa/

Comment: Because when percentage is used, `margin-top` will use the **width** of the parent to calculate, not the height. [WebPlatform doc](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/css/properties/margin-top#Values), [W3 doc](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#margin-properties).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the containers to span the entire visible height of the window, then this is easy to accomplish by switching the `height` and `margin-top` units from `%` to `vh` which is a unit that represents 1/100th of the the view-port height.

```
.leftcontainer{
    position: relative;
    float:left;
    width:60%;
    height:100vh;
}
.rightcontainer{
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    width:40%;
    height:100vh;
}
.textbox{
    margin-top: 50vh;
    width: 100%;
    background:#333333;
}
```

http://jsbin.com/ahAfUba/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: If you use `vh`, you'll drop IE<=8, most Android, Opera Presto, and some old Safari: http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units